# Android obfuscate is not working

Tags: android

My requirement;--

In my Android Project(**Example1**) I am using another android project as library(**Example2**)..

This **example2** has below class:--

```
public class **Chatter1** {
     public static final String info = "busyMan";
        public static final String pres = "SeeYou";

        public Chatter1()
        {
        }
}
```

Now,After use Proguard(for **obfuscate**), I want to hide this strings of this class..

So in my "Project.properties" I have done:--

```
-injars Example2
-outjars example2
-libraryjars Example2

-printmapping mapping.txt
-verbose
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}



-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends com.example2.chatter1


-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

But Still I can fetch the strings from Chatter1 class.It is not hiding.How Can I hide this strings???

****Is it possible to hide string value by obfuscate??how can I do that??

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard cannot obfuscate/encrypt constants. You may want to implement your own obfuscation code or try DexGuard: http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard.

Comment: With this "dexguard"..how can I hide string value?? Can you please give any example?

Comment: First of all, you have to buy it... :)